# In place factories and uninitialized space requirement : if by-member construction elision were permited

Tags: c++, placement-new, class-constructors

let us consider this boost document:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/utility/in_place_factories.html

extract:

```
struct C
{
   template<class InPlaceFactory>
   C ( InPlaceFactory const& aFactoty )
    :
    contained_ ( uninitialized_storage() )
   {
     aFactory.template apply<X>(contained_);
   }

  char* uninitialized_storage() { return new char[sizeof(X)] ; }

  char* contained_ ;
} ;
```

In effect, because the C++ compiler calls the class members constructors during initialization list, we cannot extend the arguments from the in-place-factory without some pre-processor (or pre-compiler). Therefore to avoid the default constructor to be called, we change the type of the member, to `char*`.

What I state, is that this is sad.

Imagine that `contained_` was of the intended type `X`:

**isn't there a way to prevent the constructor from being called at all** ? Letting the member in an uninitialized state, the same way as if it was just a pool of bytes with the correct space and alignment requirement for the type, and then we are free to call the constructors we want, using `placement new` (which is exactly what in-place-factory does) ?

This way, we would not have alignment problems, or readability problems because "what could be stored in that `char*` ? whatever"

And we could use in-place-factory notation, but over a `X` type, and not a `char*` type.

Also, when thinking about the answer, please always keep in mind that your solution should be able to work directly in place, if the struct `C` is instanciated on the stack, I want no pointers and no heap allocation, the `contained_` object must stay in-place, on the stack.

You notice that the original boost solution uses `new` to benefit from a 16 bytes alignment (gone 32 bytes for objects larger than 4096 in Microsoft CRT 2014). Effectively avoiding the alignment problems caused by the otherwise more natural notation that would have been:

`char contained_[sizeof(X)];`

of course the "fix" would be to use something like `__declspec(align(alignof(X)))` before the declaration of `contained_`, but like I said, using char arrays is hardly a maintainable solution, forcing us to cast everytime we want to use `contained_`...

thanks !

Comment: There is no way to call the correct destructor then, also that is left to user? A way to overcome that I think is to use mixins to create in-place composite objects on the fly. Do you think you'll accept the mixing version as answer? :P Also note that the alignment is not only 32, certain types (SSE AVX) requires an even stricter alignment (128 bit)

Comment: wow 128 is very stringent, I guess people writing AVX code must take a great deal of care. I don't understand what are mixins/composite objects just by reading the words, and you know, only 12 people viewed this page so you can go ahead and post anything, that would never hurt !